# Exception: invalid_request: must use HTTP POST

Tags: aws-lambda

I'm invoking sfinvokeapi lmabda function and this error is in output. Even thought in class it is a post method.

START RequestId: 2ab53af9-8cce-4531-8e6d-49814b50c4a0 Version: $LATEST

[INFO]    2023-08-12T22:33:29.489Z    2ab53af9-8cce-4531-8e6d-49814b50c4a0    event: {"Details": {"Parameters": {"sf_operation": "lookup", "homephone": "+441122334455", "sf_object": "Contact", "sf_fields": "Id, Name"}}}

[INFO]    2023-08-12T22:33:29.753Z    2ab53af9-8cce-4531-8e6d-49814b50c4a0    Found credentials in environment variables.

[INFO]    2023-08-12T22:33:30.112Z    2ab53af9-8cce-4531-8e6d-49814b50c4a0    Loading credentials

[INFO]    2023-08-12T22:33:30.415Z    2ab53af9-8cce-4531-8e6d-49814b50c4a0    Credentials Loaded

[INFO]    2023-08-12T22:33:30.415Z    2ab53af9-8cce-4531-8e6d-49814b50c4a0    Salesforce: Query

[INFO]    2023-08-12T22:33:30.415Z    2ab53af9-8cce-4531-8e6d-49814b50c4a0    GET Requests:

url=https://dooneyandbourke--dev.sandbox.lightning.force.com/services/data/v58.0/query

params={'q': "SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE homephone LIKE '%112%233%4455%'"}

[INFO]    2023-08-12T22:33:30.810Z    2ab53af9-8cce-4531-8e6d-49814b50c4a0    Response: [{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]

[INFO]    2023-08-12T22:33:30.811Z    2ab53af9-8cce-4531-8e6d-49814b50c4a0    Retrieving new Salesforce OAuth token

[INFO]    2023-08-12T22:33:30.811Z    2ab53af9-8cce-4531-8e6d-49814b50c4a0    POST Requests:

url=https://dooneyandbourke--dev.sandbox.lightning.force.com/services/oauth2/token

[ERROR]   2023-08-12T22:33:31.234Z    2ab53af9-8cce-4531-8e6d-49814b50c4a0    invalid_request: must use HTTP POST

[ERROR] Exception: invalid_request: must use HTTP POST

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/var/task/sfInvokeAPI.py", line 55, in lambda_handler

resp = lookup(sf=sf, **event['Details']['Parameters'])

File "/var/task/sfInvokeAPI.py", line 90, in lookup

records = sf.query(query=query)

File "/var/task/salesforce.py", line 89, in query

resp = self.makeRequest(self.request.get, **{"url": url, "params":{'q':query}})

File "/var/task/salesforce.py", line 188, in makeRequest

resp = self.request.post(url=self.login_host+"/services/oauth2/token", params=self.auth_data, headers=headers, hideData=True)

File "/var/task/salesforce.py", line 215, in post

return _*check_resp*_(r)

File "/var/task/salesforce.py", line 246, in _*check_resp*_

raise Exception(msg)

END RequestId: 2ab53af9-8cce-4531-8e6d-49814b50c4a0

REPORT RequestId: 2ab53af9-8cce-4531-8e6d-49814b50c4a0  Duration: 1823.08 ms    Billed Duration: 1824 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 62 MB  Init Duration: 659.55 ms

in salesforce.py class this is the function

```
 try:
      return requestMethod(**kwargs, headers=self.headers)
    except InvalidAuthTokenException as e:
      # try re-fetching auth token
      logger.info("Retrieving new Salesforce OAuth token")
      headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
      resp = self.request.post(url=self.login_host+"/services/oauth2/token", params=self.auth_data, headers=headers, hideData=True)
      data = resp.json()
      self.auth_token = self.secrets["AuthToken"] = data['access_token']
      self.headers = kwargs['headers'] = { 
        'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % self.auth_token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.